# Creating a new column with constant value in .Xdf file using rxDataStep

Tags: r, constants, revolution-r

Could any one tell me how to create a new column having constant value in .Xdf file without taking data into dataframe.

I have a date type global variable named `mod_run_date` having value as `"2014-05-01"` . I want to create a new column `CV_PROCESSED_AS_OF_DT` in  `"/poc/revor/data/selective_acceptance_inter.xdf"` having value as `"2014-05-01"` for all rows.

Have tried below code for the same:

```
rxDataStep(inData = "/poc/revor/data/selective_acceptance_inter.xdf",outFile = "/poc/revor/data/selective_acceptance.xdf",
transform = list(CV_PROCESSED_AS_OF_DT = mod_run_date),transformObjects = list(mod_run_date = mod_run_date),
overwrite = TRUE)
```

But getting error that

```
argument 3 matches multiple formal arguments
```

Could anyone point out the mistake I am doing in the code or any other approach to obtain the same.

Thanks in advance for your help...:)

Cheers,

Amit

Answer (score 0):

The issue us that you haven't fully specified the proper argument. You need `transforms`, not `transform`.  The problem with `transform` is alluded to by your error, ie it could be `transforms`, `transformFunc`, or `transformObjects`.